# My code is not working on button click but works when you reload in Firefox developer

Tags: javascript, html

Code Seems to work when you reload in Firefox developer, and the values are not changed, i assume Firefox is running code with values entered in previous session, Also doesn't seem to work on safari this way.  Copy of JS & HTML Code posted below, I tried debugging and first it showed error with "||" command I later replaced with "&&" but the problem persisted later I placed the "||" and the debugger showed no errors.

```
function calculateTip() {
  var billAmt = document.getElementById("billamt").value;
  var serviceQual = document.getElementById("servicequal").value;
  var numOfPeople = document.getElementById("people").value;
  //validate input
  if (billAmt === "") && serviceQual == 0) {
    alert("Please enter values");
    return;
  }

  if(numOfPeople === "" || numOfPeople <= 1) {
    numOfPeople = 1;
    document.getElementById("each").style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("each").style.display = "block";
  }

  var total = (billAmt * serviceQual) / numOfPeople;
  total = Math.round(total * 100) / 100;
  total =total.toFixed(2);

  document.getElementById("totaltip").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("tip").innerHTML = total;

}

document.getElementById("totaltip").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("each").style.display = "none";

document.getElementById("calculate").onclick = function() {
  calculateTip();

};
 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<div id="container">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="tipcal.css" type="text/css">
<h1> Tip Calculator </h1>
<div id="calculator">

 <form>
    <input id="billamt" type="text" placeholder="Bill Amount">

    <p> How was your service
      <p>
        <select id="servicequal">
          <option disabled selected value="0"> -- Chose and Option </option>
          <option value="0.3">30&#37; &#45;
            Outstanding</option> <!-- Useful bit of code for min customisation -->
            <option value="0.2">20&#37; &#45;
              Good </option>
              <option value="0.1">10&#37; &#45;
                It was ok </option>
                <option value="0">0&#37; &#45;
                  Terrible </option>
                </select>

              </form>

              <p> How many were sharing the bill </p>
              <input id="people" type="text" placeholder="Number of people"> People
              <button type="button" id="calculate"> calculate </button>

            </div>

            <div id="totaltip">
              <sup> $ </sup> <span id="tip">0.00</span>
              <small id="each"> each </small>
            </div>

          </div>

          <script src="tipcal.js"></script>
```

Comment: you better check the console on your browser. it has helpful info if there are errors on the code. and you can also put a break-point on your code just to trace which part you're getting the error.

Answer (score 1):

`Click` is working, you have made a mistake over here `if (billAmt === "") && serviceQual == 0) {`

```js
function calculateTip() {
alert('clicked');
  var billAmt = document.getElementById("billamt").value;
  var serviceQual = document.getElementById("servicequal").value;
  var numOfPeople = document.getElementById("people").value;
  //validate input
  if ((billAmt === "") && serviceQual == 0) {
    alert("Please enter values");
    return;
  }

  if(numOfPeople === "" || numOfPeople <= 1) {
    numOfPeople = 1;
    document.getElementById("each").style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("each").style.display = "block";
  }

  var total = (billAmt * serviceQual) / numOfPeople;
  total = Math.round(total * 100) / 100;
  total =total.toFixed(2);

  document.getElementById("totaltip").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("tip").innerHTML = total;

}

document.getElementById("totaltip").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("each").style.display = "none";

document.getElementById("calculate").onclick = function() {
  calculateTip();

};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<div id="container">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="tipcal.css" type="text/css">
<h1> Tip Calculator </h1>
<div id="calculator">

 <form>
    <input id="billamt" type="text" placeholder="Bill Amount">

    <p> How was your service
      <p>
        <select id="servicequal">
          <option disabled selected value="0"> -- Chose and Option </option>
          <option value="0.3">30&#37; &#45;
            Outstanding</option> <!-- Useful bit of code for min customisation -->
            <option value="0.2">20&#37; &#45;
              Good </option>
              <option value="0.1">10&#37; &#45;
                It was ok </option>
                <option value="0">0&#37; &#45;
                  Terrible </option>
                </select>

              </form>

              <p> How many were sharing the bill </p>
              <input id="people" type="text" placeholder="Number of people"> People
              <button type="button" id="calculate"> calculate </button>

            </div>

            <div id="totaltip">
              <sup> $ </sup> <span id="tip">0.00</span>
              <small id="each"> each </small>
            </div>

          </div>
```

Comment: I have tried the code with removing that particular if statement. Still doesn't work

Comment: if you got alert with message "clicked", then you click event is working fine.